# Replace multiple substrings of Pandas Series at once

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, series

I have a Pandas Series of golf scores with multiple substring replacements I would like to make simultaneously:

1. Replace '+' with '' (i.e. nothing)
2. Replace 'E' with '0'

In a dictionary, I suppose this would look like:

```
reps = {'+' : '', 'E' : '0'}
```

I have tried pandas.Series.str.replace, but that only seems to accept one argument. What I've done so far is this:

```
series = series.str.replace('+', '')
series = series.str.replace('E', '0')
```

This works, but is obviously poor form. How can I do this in one line, with any number of edits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using python3 (this won't work in python2), you can use [`pandas.Series.str.translate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.translate.html) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
reps = {'+' : '', 'E' : '0'}
series = pd.Series(['+1', 'E', '+5', '-1'])

print(series)
#0    +1
#1     E
#2    +5
#3    -1
#dtype: object

print(series.str.translate(str.maketrans(reps)))
#0     1
#1     0
#2     5
#3    -1
#dtype: object
```

A better way to verify that it's doing what you expect:

```
print(series.str.translate(str.maketrans(reps)).values)
#array(['1', '0', '5', '-1'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

A loop here should be sufficient

```
for key,value in reps.items():
    series = series.str.replace(key,value)
```

Answer (score 1):

How to replace the special mark

```
series.replace({'[+]': '', 'E': '0'},regex=True)
Out[778]: 
0     1
1     0
2     5
3    -1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Let *a* be your series

```
a.map(lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('+E',' 0')))
```

This is convenient because it will remain a single line, regardless of the number of replacements to be made.

Comment: except that this replaces the `+` with a space, not an empty string as requested by OP. You can `print(a.map(lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('+E',' 0'))).values)` to verify

Answer (score 0):

Potentially overkill, but you could also do it like this:

```
def replace_substr(your_string, for_removal):
    for old, new in for_removal.items():
        x =  your_string.replace(old, new)
    return x 

df['series'] = df['series'].apply(lambda x: replace_substr(x, reps))
```